# Regex sentence shouldn't start or end with "

Tags: regex, expression

How does the regular expression work, so that no **"** characters are allowed at the beginning and the end of a sentence. Examples:

```
Test "if" that works --> is allowed
"Test" if that works --> is not allowed
Test if that "works" --> is also not allowed
```

So the quotes are only allowed in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
^(?!").*(?<!")$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zdUDgI/1)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check depending on which language you're using, but you can use the regex `'^\"|\"$'` to capture a string with a quotation mark (") at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: now I can capture a string but how to disallow that exactly?

Comment: It depends how you have the strings stored, for example if you have it as a list of strings you could iterate through the list, check each example and create a new list of good examples.

Comment: our language in this case is ABAP

Comment: @invasion please don't forget to select the most suitable answer and mark with a tick! Thanks